# Alterar branch global para main no ubuntu 20

Tags: git, ubuntu, branch

Como eu faço para alterar de forma definitiva (global) a branch do git de "master" para "main" no ubuntu 20?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O comando `git-config` permite isso.
O parametro `init.defaultBranch`, como diz a documentação permite definir outro nome para o branch usado na initialização de um novo repositório ou quando se clona um repositório já existente. O âmbito desta definição depende do modificador usado (--system, --global, --worktree, --file ou --local).

Da documentação `https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config`

```
init.defaultBranch
  Allows overriding the default branch name e.g. when initializing a new repository or 
  when cloning an empty repository.
```